# Javascript textbox call event when value changes

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have a textbox, and whenever the value of the box changes, I want to check and see if 20 digits have been entered.

I thought that I would use the `onChange` event, but this seems to be interpreted as the `onBlur` event on IE.

So then I thought I would use `onKeyDown`, but the problem comes in if the user wants to paste a value into the field, then the function never gets called.

There are no other form boxes so I can't rely on `onBlur` or expect that they will change focus ever.

How do I do this?

I just want to evaluate the value of the textbox every time the value of the textbox changes.

```
<input type="text" onKeyDown="myfunction()">
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

An effective way is to use a combination of `onkeydown` and `onpaste`, which will work in IE, Firefox, Chrome and Safari.  Opera is the odd one out here because it doesn't support `onpaste` so you may have to fall back to `onchange` for Opera or use the `DOMAttrModified` mutation event, see example below.

Internet Explorer also supports `onpropertychange`, which will fire every time a property changes on an element -- including `value`.  I have read that `DOMAttrModified` is supported by Opera and Safari (not sure about Firefox), so you could use that in combination with IE's `onpropertychange` (untested):

```
if ("implementation" in document &&
                   document.implementation.hasFeature('MutationEvents','2.0'))
    myInput.addEventListener("DOMAttrModified", valueChanged, false);    
else if ("onpropertychange" in myInput)
    myInput.onpropertychange = valueChanged;

function valueChanged (evt)
{
    var attr;
    evt = evt || window.event;
    attr = evt.attrName || evt.propertyName;

    if (attr == "value")
        validate();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use `onKeryPress` event

```
 <input type="text" onKeyDown="CountText(this,200)" onpaste="return false;"> 

    function CountText(field, maxlimit) 
    {
       if (field.value.length < maxlimit) // if too long...trim it!
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
          return false;
    }
```

check my full article on : http://www.codeproject.com/KB/validation/MyTextBox.aspx

Comment: `keydown` and `keypress` are not the same.  Pick one.  `keyup` would be the best if you want the majority of key events, but don't need to know when keys repeat (you'll just be notified when the key is finally released).  If you need to recognize changed immediately, use `keydown`.  `keypress` ignores non-printing keys, like backspace.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <script>

function multy(val)
{
alert(val.value+"--"+val.id);
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
<input id="txtdemo" type="text" onchange="multy(this);"></br>
<input id="txtdemo" type="text" onchange="multy(this);">
</input>
</body>
```

[image: Click to see out put screen.]

Thanks... :)