# How can I check if my value in text box were changed?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [javascript textbox call event when value changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2829491/javascript-textbox-call-event-when-value-changes)

How can I check if my value in text box were changed?
without using a button...(updated automatiicaly in javascript!)

Comment: Check the answer to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2829491/javascript-textbox-call-event-when-value-changes

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
<input type="text" id="myInput" onchange="alert('changed')" />
```